# Convert 2D affine transformation matrix to 3D affine transformation matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, transformation, linear-algebra

I have a bug somewhere in my code, was wondering if this is incorrect.

I have a 2D view matrix in my code, but to display my world to the screen I need to convert the 2D view matrix to a 3D one. This is the process that I am using:

```
| a b c |      | a b c 0 |
| d e f |  =>  | d e f 0 |
| g h i |      | g h i 0 |
               | 0 0 0 1 |
```

It works when I use an identity matrix for the 2D matrix, but as soon as I apply any transforms to the 2D matrix all my objects being drawn disappear.

For drawing in 2D using 3D, I use this projection matrix:

```
_basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
```

What is the correct way to transform the 2D matrix to 3D?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Affine transformations use the extra row/column of the transformation matrix for translation. So I think what you want to do is to move the last row/column down/right and then for the new axis simply insert the identity transformation.

```
| a b c |      | a b 0 c |
| d e f |  =>  | d e 0 f |
| g h i |      | 0 0 1 0 |
               | g h 0 i |
```

I'm not sure, but give it a try at least.